# Refresh LinearLayout size

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to have a square imageview in my app and I made a custom ImageView :

```
namespace Blood_Pressure_Notebook.Widget
{
    public class SquareImageView : ImageView
    {
        public int SquareMode { get; set; } = 0;

    public SquareImageView(Context context) : base(context) { }
    public SquareImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        Android.Content.Res.TypedArray ta = Context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, Resource.Styleable.SquareImageView);
        this.SquareMode = ta.GetInt(Resource.Styleable.SquareImageView_SquareMode, 0);
        ta.Recycle();
    }
    public SquareImageView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) { }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (SquareMode == 0)
        {
            SetMeasuredDimension(MeasuredWidthAndState, MeasuredWidthAndState);
        }
        else if (SquareMode == 1)
        {
            SetMeasuredDimension(MeasuredHeight, MeasuredHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

}

and I use it here:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      app:cardElevation="2dp"
      app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
      app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
      app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
      app:contentPadding="0dp">
      <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        **<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl">
          **<blood_pressure_notebook.widget.SquareImageView
              android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/imgImage"
              android:scaleType="centerInside"
              android:layout_weight="0.2" 
              android:adjustViewBounds="true"
              app:SquareMode="0"/>**
          <TextView
              android:text="Medium Text"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/txtName"
              android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
              android:layout_weight="0.8"
              android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />
        </LinearLayout>**
        <TextView
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/txtDescription" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
          <ImageView
              android:src="@drawable/ic_account_box_black_24dp"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/imgLogin"
              android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
          <ImageView
              android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_black_24dp"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/imgEdit"
              android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The imageview size changes without any problem but height of its parent (LinearLayout) doesn't change and stays large!

My question is how to refresh or update the LinearLayout?

I've tried Invalidate() and setting LayoutParameter but nothing changed.